# Firefox nightly Icon missing

Tags: firefox, icons, 18.04

The icon of Firefox nightly is missing in the launcher (I have an empty space instead) since month. I did the update of Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04, but it did not solve anything, the icon is still missing.  Nightly is updated...every night, but the icon is never there.

Does someone know how to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set an icon for Nightly. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Open Files and go to your `/usr/share/applications` folder. Look for the "Nightly" file and copy it.
2. Paste the file in `~/.local/share/applications`. It should look like a file with the name `<filename>.desktop`. (If there is already one `.desktop` file for Firefox Nightly in `~/.local/share/applications` you don't have to copy & paste.)
3. Right click on this `.desktop` file and open with Text Editor.
4. Look for a line starting with `Icon=`. Change it to

   ```
   Icon=/full/path/to/your/preferred/icon-image
   ```
5. Save the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, I did not find any Nightly file in the /usr/share/applications folder.

Comment: @Philetjosie How are you launching Nightly? Can you find it after clicking on"Activities" and searching for it? Also look for it in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. However, I did not find any Nightly file in the /usr/share/applications folder.
But I found the nightly.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications 
Here is its content, i checked that the file mozicon128.png exists at the right place, so I do not understand whats the problem.

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Nightly
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Actions=Default;Mozilla;ProfileManager;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23

[Desktop Action Default]
Name=Default Profile
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox

[Desktop Action Mozilla]
Name=Mozilla Profile
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox

[Desktop Action ProfileManager]
Name=Profile Manager
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox --no-remote --profile-manager

Comment: Hello, the link to the icons was wrong, i fix it and now it works. Many thanks !!