# How to Pin Firefox Development Version to Ubuntu Dock on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firefox, .desktop, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

How do you pin Firefox Development Version to the dock of Ubuntu 18.04?  When I ran it goes to the Dash board but a right click does not show option to add to favorites?

Comment: If dragging to dock to the dock doesn't work, see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-dock-add-to-favorites

Comment: See this for missing icon issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032274/firefox-nightly-icon-missing

Comment: All is set now thanks to all!  I wish Ubuntu has a documentation as good as say Freebsd.